# Litsgroupitem with vertically centered text and button on the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list-group where I want to show some elements which can be added dynamically through another component inside the page.
What I need is button where the user can remove such element. The button should be aligned right hand side.

So this is what I came up with by now:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <span>Item to delete</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger pull-righ">
            <i class="fa fa-times "/>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Problem is, that the text is not vertically centered, the button instead is.

[image]

If I remove the button's `pull-right` class, the button is for sure not aligned anymore, but the text is vertically centered to the button.

[image]

How can I have both? Vertically centered text with the button placed on the right side?

Already tried putting the button inside its own `span` element and applying classes or element-styles, e.g. `vertical-align`, different `display` or `line-height`. But as far as I know, most of them do need a hight set for the parent element (which I don't have).
On the other hand it seems to do what I want as long as there is no `pull-right` for the button.

Comment: Try using flex, thats the easy way i think

Answer (score 0):

Here is code, i used `display: flex` and to align the content, is used `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
li.list-group-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <span>Item to delete</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger pull-righ">
            <i class="fa fa-times "></i>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox for this. `align-items` will do what you need.

```css
.list-group-item {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <span>Item to delete</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger pull-right">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform: translateY(37%)` with Bootstrap.

```css
li span {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translateY(37%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
        <span>Item to delete</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can also check this [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/bwas19rd/)

**Note:** It's better to go with `flex css` for your requirement.